# Showing markers on Google Fusion Tables map based on template by Derek Eder?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am working on a map based on the template made by Derek Eder found at http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/.

The data is from a Google Fusion Table. Here is what I have so far: http://andyinman.com/derekeder/index.html.

The problem is that only the first four types of crime (the check boxes) show up as markers on the map. The ones in black text do not show up. Why is this? They are drawn from a column in the fusion table called "type" and assigned a numerical value of 1 through 11.

The results show up as "Results found" but do not show up on the map. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is right. I think the problem is with your Fusion Table (https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=4695503).

You are using the 'Location' column for searching, but it looks like that column has only been partially geocoded. I'd try going in to Fusion Tables and try File => Geocode on the 'Location' column and see if that works.

If that fails, try setting the 'locationColumn' variable from 'Location' to 'lat'

Comment: You were right... the column was not fully geocoded, apparently. It is working now. http://andyinman.com/derekeder/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the [FusionTablesLayer functionality of Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables):

- You can add up to 5 FusionTablesLayer to your map (you are currently setting a new one for every search, not very efficient, but I don't think that's the problem)
- You may have only one styled layer
- On that styled layer you may have up to 5 styling rules

I think you are running in the 3rd limit, because you are trying to style the markers for each type differently (i.e. different color). If you limit the styling, it should work.

The other solution would be to [add the markers yourself](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers), then you don't have these limitations, but for this amount of markers this is going to be a performance issue.